# Rails access a file stored on S3 (`method_missing': undefined method `[]')

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to instantiate a file stored on s3 with rails to parse it. The first step is to access the file. I have built a quick script to get familiar with amazon aws-sdk gem.

```
require 'aws-sdk'
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(
access_key_id: 'XXXX',
secret_access_key: 'XXXX',
region: 'us-east-1')

bucket = s3.bucket('my_bucket')

bucket.objects.each do |obj|
puts obj.key
end
```

This code will give me the list of all the objects (files) on my drive. It looks like

```
uploads/doc1.pdf
uploads/doc2.pdf
```

Now I want to understand how I can retrieve one single object. I tried

```
object = bucket.objects['doc2.pdf']
puts object.key
```

But I get the error `method_missing': undefined method`[]' for Aws::Resources::Collection:0x0055e82a514ab0> (NoMethodError)

I also tried

```
 object = bucket.objects.find(1)
 puts object.name
```

But I get the error undefined method `name' for Enumerator:0x0055855a098de8> (NoMethodError)

Could anyone give me the right syntax to retrieve one single object (file)? Once I get it, I intend to use the "open" method to instantiate the file and then a pdf parser. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has worked for me

```
object = bucket.object('path to file')
```